# Error using rvest download.file to download a pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, rvest

I would like to use download.file in rvest package to download a pdf. The link is as followed. 
https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/ABA/Derivations3.pdf

my code is

```
download.file("https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/ABA/Derivations3.pdf",destfile = "d3.pdf")
```

It does download a 1.7mb pdf file, but it's all blank when I open it. The other pdf files I tried to download has error messaged saying it is damaged.

Why the download.file command can't download pdf files?

Answer (score 5):

Since the library is intended for web scraping, and web pages are text, it stands to reason that the default write mode of `download.file` is ASCII.

Try specifying binary mode (`mode = "wb"`) in your call.

```
download.file("https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/ABA/Derivations3.pdf", destfile = "d3.pdf", mode = "wb")
```